# Using a dropdown in Access, display and save a name field pulling from either of 3 tables with a common key

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

In my Access DB, I have 3 tables with the following fields:

```
Contributors
| ContributorId (PK) | ContributorName |
+--------------------+-----------------+
|        1           |    Jane Doe     |
|        2           |    George Wish  |
```

```
ContributorSpouses
| SpouseId (PK) |    SpouseName    | ContributorId (FK) |
+---------------+------------------+--------------------+
|        1      |    Karen Wish    |          2         |
|        2      |    John Doe      |          1         |
```

```
ContributorBusinesses
| BusinessId (PK) |     BusinessName    | ContributorId (FK) |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------+
|         1       |  John's Pizza, Inc  |          2         |
|         2       |  Do Doe Dough, LLP  |          2         |
|         3       |  Jane's Nail Salon  |          2         |
|         4       |  Georges Car Wash   |          1         |
```

I have a 4th table -

```
Donations
| DonationId (PK) | DonationAmount | ContributorId (FK) |
+-----------------+----------------+--------------------+
|         1       |     180.00     |          1         |
|         2       |     300.00     |          2         |
|         3       |      10.00     |          2         |
|         4       |    4000.00     |          2         |
```

This table is being used in the following form:
[image]

This was good as long I only needed `Contributors.ContributorName` to show up in the "Contributor" dropdown in the above screenshot.
*(Note: `ContributorId` is currently bound to the first column of this query (row source)
`SELECT c.ContributorId, c.ContributorName FROM Contributors c ORDER BY c.ContributorName;`
and therefore displays the `ContributorName` Contributor dropdown, but actually saves only the `ContributorId`.)*
However, a contributor may sometimes donate from their business and another time donate personally (or through their spouse) and they would want their tax receipt to reflect that.

I want the Contributor dropdown to display a union of `ContributorName`, `SpouseName` and `BusinessName` as follows:

George Wish
Jane Doe
John Doe
Karen Wish
Do Doe Dough, LLP
Georges Car Wash
Jane's Nail Salon
John's Pizza, Inc

and save the selection along with the `ContributorId` to the `Donations` table.

I created a new table:

```
ContributorNameTypes
| ContributorNameTypeId |   ContributorNameType   |
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
|            1          |     ContributorName     |
|            2          |  ContributorSpouseName  |
|            3          | ContributorBusinessName |
```

I was thinking of making 1 more table which would have

```
ContributorNames
| ContributorNameId | ContributorNameTypeId |
+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

with both fields combining as a PK.
The `ContributorNameId` in this table refers to one of the following - `Contributors.ContributorId`, `ContributorSpouses.SpouseId`, or
`ContributorBusinesses.BusinessId`.

However, I'm getting stuck here.
How do I make that relationship between one of the 3 name types and the tables they should connect to.
After that, how would I have everything show up in the drop down?

Comment: Don't couples contribute as a unit? But if you want to have separate records for each, surely a spouse could be a contributor? I would have one table for people with a column for SpouseID. A query to associate contributor with spouse would be a self-join of People table. And since you have contributing businesses, I might even have 1 table for all Contributors. This would mean some unused fields (business would not have spouse). A DonorType field could be in this table. I see no need to complicate with DonatorNameTypes table since each contributor can be only one type.

Comment: And I see only two types: individual and business.

Comment: Whether or not couples contribute as a unit is not relevant in my scenario. There are a number of other fields in each table that don't relate to this question, so I left it out. But I do want those 3 separate tables due to everything else in each table. I can certainly restructure these tables into something that 's cleaner, but I don't think the db set up badly enough to warrant that headache.

Comment: Regardless, I still don't see need for DonatorNameTypes junction table.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just reread my question and realized that it didn't all make sense. I edited the question to reflect what I meant and it should make more sense now.

Comment: Doesn't change my comments. Use a UNION query to combine multiple tables to one merged dataset.

Comment: What do you mean by 'through their spouse'? If spouse's name is on donation then they are the donor. Same for their business. Are you saying you want tax receipt to reflect spouse or business info? That would seem to be normal.

Comment: Yes, sometimes the tax receipt should reflect the spouse or business info.